# Mongo index of array item

Tags: php, mongodb

Good afternoon,

I was wondering if someone could fill me in. Is it possible to find the index of an array object which is an array inside a document? Using the document below I want to know the index of the object inside items which has a userid of 15 (in this case the index being 1).

Is this possible and if so how would I go around doing this find()?

```
    {
      "_id" : ObjectId("4fb6c4791e1a121434000000"),
      "set" : "2",
      "items" : [{
                  "image" : "",
                  "userid" : 14
       }, {
                  "image" : "",
                  "userid" : 15
       }]
    }
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Adding to this I have come across db.foo.find()._addSpecial("$returnKey" , true ) would this find the array index does anyone know?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any method that allows you to do this directly. I don't know the rest of your schema, or what this document really contains so it's virtually impossible to suggest alternatives. (If you update the question, I'll update my answer)